# How to get a slice of a dataframe with boolean indexing that can modify the original

Tags: python, pandas

Say we have a dataframe as such:

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame({'A':[5,5,5,5,5,5],
                        'B':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
dataset
    A   B
0   5   1
1   5   2
2   5   3
3   5   4
4   5   5
5   5   6
```

Getting a normal slice of 1 to 4 gives us

```
ds = dataset[1:4]
ds
    A   B
1   5   2
2   5   3
3   5   4
```

While getting a slice through boolean indexing gives us

```
sliced = dataset.loc[dataset['B'] % 2 == 0]
sliced
    A   B
1   5   2
3   5   4
5   5   6
```

I'm trying to edit the original dataset with the slice gotten through the boolean indexing method. When doing it with normal slicing it works as expected

```
ds.loc[1,'A'] = 10
ds
    A   B
1   10  2
2   5   3
3   5   4

dataset
    A   B
0   5   1
1   10  2
2   5   3
3   5   4
4   5   5
5   5   6
```

But when editing the boolean indexed slice it doesn't change the original

```
sliced.loc[1,'A'] = 10
sliced
    A   B
1   10  2
3   5   4
5   5   6


dataset
    A   B
0   5   1
1   5   2
2   5   3
3   5   4
4   5   5
5   5   6
```

I couldn't find anything in the docs about boolean indexing creating a copy instead of a view (I'm not totally sure if that is even the right terminology). I've tried adding .loc to the slices and that didn't seem to change anything. I even tried ds._is_copy() and sliced._is_copy() but they both return the same thing, a weakref to the original dataframe. ._is_view seems to return True or False almost randomly but according to the source code it doesn't seem too reliable anyway.

> def is_view(self) -> bool:
>
> """ return a boolean if I am possibly a view """

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is (as documentation says, for example in the link of the "caveat" warning you've certainly seen many times while trying to alter the content of a sub dataframe. For example, you just saw it when you tried to alter `ds` values. It worked. But with a warning telling you that you shouldn't assume it does), pandas makes no guarantee about what is a view and what is a copy, when indexing.

So you are not supposed to modify a slice of a dataset. Because you cannot count on it being a view or not. Both your case are wrong. The first one (modifying `ds.loc[1,'A']`) is wrong, because you may wrongly believe that you are working with a copy, when you are not. The second one (modifying `sliced.loc[1,'A']` is wrong because you may wrongly believe that you are working with a view when you are not. You cannot easily predict in which case you are, so the impact of both of those code on the original `dataset` is UB.

Now, there is some logic here (but that is reverse engineering, nothing normalized): slice such as `1:4` is a view here, because it is easy for pandas to just return a subset of rows. In the underlying numpy array, it is the same as a slice. Likewise, `::2` to select even rows, would probably lead to a view (it does right now on my machine), for the same reason. In numpy, you can just get this array from the original one by just tweaking some strides. If you even think in `C`, you can just iterate the slice data with a simple `for(char *p=start; p<end; p+=stride)` by using the same data, but different start, end and stride. So, why would pandas bother copying those data, if it is not necessary? The only reason to make a copy is because of the risk of people unwillingly alter original data by altering the slice... but documentation (and the warning you've ignored) explicitly says that you shouldn't do that.

Slice such as `[dataset['B']%2==1]` is probably a copy, because this time, there aren't any way to just return a dataframe made of the same data, with a different start, end and stride. So pandas just needs to make a copy. Which, again, doesn't matter, since you are not supposed to modify it, so no risk that you unwillingly alter only a local copy.

But even in such case, you cannot count on the fact that it is a copy. For example, in your very case, that slice happens to be the same you would got with `dataset[1::2]`. And this one returns a view, not a copy.
So, you can't swear that, in the future, there won't be a super-optimized pandas version, able to realize that `dataset[dataset.B%2==1]` is the same as `dataset.loc[1::2]`, and taking advantage of that to avoid a costly copy.

So, long story short: do as the warning you got says; don't try to modify content of a sliced dataframe. And instead, use `.loc[slice, column]=...` syntax.

```
dataset.loc[1:4, 'A']=10
dataset.loc[dataset.B%2==1, 'A']=15
```

Answer (score 0):

At the first case (using boolean indexing method) you didn't change' the current meaning of dataset. You got the dataset according of condition dataset['B'] % 2 == 0. It's a filter. But at the next case you  used the assignment operator and you've got changing in the link on the part of the main dataset. And It is changed the main dataset.
Because ds = dataset[1:4] - it's a link on the part of the main dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating `ds` and `sliced` differently. One creates a reference, once creates a copy.

Comment: I know that. I guess part of my question boils down to why they create different types of results and how to make sliced be a reference instead of a copy. The docs don't seem to mention anything about boolean indexing creating a copy instead of a reference or in what situations either one is created.

Comment: @nemba As I said longly in my answer, the only answer to you "why" is "because". There is no reason. What that warning says is "pandas indexing works in mysterious way, and you are not supposed to try to guess whether it is a view or a copy"